# Query to get data in particular format in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-views

My Models:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=25)


class Subject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Student_subject_mapping(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I'm trying to get all `Student_subject_mapping` data in the database in a format:

What will be the query to get the data in the following manner?
How can I achieve data in the above format?

My view:

```
class Get_Students(APIView):

    def get(self, request):

        try:
            res = StudentSerializer(Student.objects.all(), many=True).data
            print({"results": res})
            return Response({"results": res}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

models.py

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=25)

class Subject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Student_subject_mapping(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='subjects')
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

serializers.py

---

```
class StudentSubjectMappingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_id(self, obj):
        return obj.subject.id

    def get_name(self, obj):
        return obj.subject.name

    class Meta:
        model = Student_subject_mapping
        fields = ['id', 'name']

class StudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    subjects = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_subjects(self, obj):
        return StudentSubjectMappingSerializer(obj.subjects.all(), many=True).data

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ['id', 'email', 'subjects']
```

your query

```
subjects = StudentSerializer(Student.objects.all(), many=True).data


print(json.dump({"results" : subjects}))
```

furthermore you don't have to create a different table for mapping, you can make use of `models.ManyToMantField` example

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    subjects = models.ManyToManyField(Subject)

class Subject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

serializers for above model structure

```
class SubjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Subject
        fields = ['id', 'name']

class StudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    subjects = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_subjects(self, obj):
        return SubjectSerializer(obj.subjects.all(), many=True).data

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ['id', 'email', 'subjects']
```

Comment: Hi Jeet, Thanks for the response but I'm getting " StudentSerializer(<QuerySet [<Student: Student object (381)>" response in this format. @Jeet

Comment: @Zodiac my bad. I forgot to write `.data` to get serialized data. I have updated my answer it should work now. Try now!

Comment: No @Jeet I am getting an error: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `name` on serializer `SubjectSerializer`.\nThe serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Student_subject_mapping` instance.\nOriginal exception text was: 'Student_subject_mapping' object has no attribute 'name'."

Comment: can you post your views.py?

Comment: yaa sure, posting !

Comment: Hey, @Jeet added view in question.

Comment: @Zodiac I updated the serializers according to your model structure and use `json.dump()` before return it. Try now.

Comment: You can refer [Django Reset Framework Documention](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/)